# Como usar uma variável de Lua em C++?

Tags: c++, lua

Não consigo pegar valor de uma matriz em Lua para usar em C++.

Assim pego o valor da variável `M`:

```
//No LUA    
M = 85  

//No C++    
L = lua_open();
luaL_loadfile(L, "teste.lua");
lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0);

int m;

lua_getglobal(L, "M");
m = lua_tonumber(L, -1);

cout << m;
```

Mas não sei como pegar o valor do índice de uma matriz como segue abaixo:

```
// LUA
MATRIZ =
{

   {4,2,2,6},
   {2,1,1,2},
   {2,1,1,2},
   {5,2,2,3}

}
```

Como pegar o valor dessa matriz?

Answer (score 4):

Você pode utilizar o método `lua_gettable`.

1. Você precisa adicionar o índice à stack via `lua_pushinteger`.
2. A key é sobreposta com o elemento.

Você também pode tentar:

```
lua_getglobal(L, "MATRIZ")
lua_rawgeti(L,-1,1) -- {4,2,2,6}
lua_rawgeti(L,-1,2) -- 2
```

Soluções vindas da minha pergunta no [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25298902/getting-array-value-from-index-using-lua-c-api)(EN).